Use value from one SQL query as column name in another SQL query
I am searching for a way to display the values of one SQL query as column names in another SQL statement. I see many examples online talking about using a pivot or crosstab. I tried both but can't really find my way out. If somebody can give me a hint in the right direction with the following:

As you can see I want to add the "Kledingmaat" as title instead of usr1 and so on.
More info: I have a table called personen, this table has 10 columns USR1, USR2, USR3, USR4, USR5, USR6, USR7, USR8, USR9, USR10. Then I have a table called uservelden which has the following columns:
VOLGNR, USERTABELNAAM, CAPTIONSTRING

How can I achieve the following result:

My SQL:
WITH ColumnNames AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 10 CAPTIONSTRING, VOLGNR
    FROM USERVELDEN
    WHERE (USERVELDNAAM LIKE 'USR[1-9]' OR USERVELDNAAM LIKE 'USR[1-9][0-9]')
      AND ACCOUNT_ID = 258
      AND USERTABELNAAM = 'PERSONEN'
    ORDER BY VOLGNR
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 1 THEN usr1 END) AS 'Kledingmaat',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 2 THEN usr2 END) AS 'Kledingmaat anders',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 3 THEN usr3 END) AS 'Dieetwensen',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 4 THEN usr4 END) AS 'Shoe size',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 5 THEN usr5 END) AS 'Fifth',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 6 THEN usr6 END) AS 'Sixth',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 7 THEN usr7 END) AS 'Seventh',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 8 THEN usr8 END) AS 'Eighth',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 9 THEN usr9 END) AS 'Ninth',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNames.VOLGNR = 10 THEN usr10 END) AS 'Tenth'
FROM 
    PERSONEN
CROSS JOIN 
    ColumnNames
WHERE 
    ACCOUNT_ID = 258
    AND INACTIEF = 'F';


Where is your code! What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Look into constructing your column aliases via dynamic SQL via STUFF

Your question is not clear - how are these fields, tables related? Indeed the straightforward answer to your question is just select usr1 as Kledingmaat, usr2 as "Kledingmaat anders", usr3 as Dieetwensen, usr4 as "Shoe size" from MyTable -- is that all you need? If you mean you need to get these column titles from another table then you probably do need what is called "dynamic sql" (and fwiw, it is probably a bad idea to even start down this path - you are not modeling data effectively with this approach).

Yes @topsail, thank you for atleast trying to help me. They are related through account_id = 258 and USERTABELNAAM = 'REL_PERSOON'

Why are you sharing a table that has titles like usr1, usr2, etc when your sample data/source table is about clothing sizes and whatnot? This is a very confusing question. Please share sample data and desired results of that sample data so we can best understand. Please also clarify if the values of Kledingmaat are known to you or you if you want the server to dynamically determine the results based on what's in the table (called a "dynamic pivot"). Lastly, please edit the tags with the RDBMS you are using (mysql, postgres, sql server, etc)

The usr1, usr2 are the values that need to be shown. So usr1 should be shown as value under the "kledingmaat". usr2 needs to be shown for "Kledingmaat anders". and so I have 10 userfields that could be filled with data. But for now I only have 4 userfields that actually are filled with data. @JNevill

these are userfields, they are meant for a user to define a field of its own. So it is not a "user" @topsail. Im sorry for the bad english and misscommunication

maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Hy3hlA34

@BartMcEndree I just added my sql query. Im not familiar with fiddle. But I will try my best

@topsail Yes, exactly

Please do not use images for data - use table markdown

Using ideas from SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?  I was able to construct this SQL-Server dynamic column solution.
This should build @cols =
'usr1 as [Kledinmaat], usr2 as [Kledinmaat anders], usr3 as [Dieetwensen], usr4 as [Shoe size]'
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',usr' + CAST(Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  as Varchar(3)) + ' as '+ QUOTENAME(c.CAPTIONSTRING) 
            FROM uservelden c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @cols

set @query = 'SELECT ' +  @cols + ' FROM personen '

execute(@query)

fiddle



Kledinmaat
Kledinmaat anders
Dieetwensen
Shoe size




null
null
null
null


null
XXX...
null
null


null
null
null
null


null
XA...
null
null


null
null
null
null


708
null
null
null


708
null
null
null


null
null
null
null


710
null
null
null


null
XS
null
null


708
null
null
null


708
null
null
null




Cool, but I need it as one sql query that I can then use within my xml file. But thats just how the application works. I added my current sql in my example above. I have a static sql now, it needs to be dynamic
